# Issue in bringing up the webapp through Apache Web server in front of Tomcat App server

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, tomcat7

I am trying to host a web-archive in an EC2 instance. This is what I did:

1. I hosted the web app in the tomcat instance (tomcat7)
2. I installed Apache Web Server and used the JK Module to make Apache to route to tomcat when someone is hitting the port 80

This is what I see in the browser for the following requests:

1. IP address in the browser (xx.xx.xx.xx) - shows me the tomcat home page
2. IP address and the webapp name (xx.xx.xx.xx/webapp) - shows me the home page of my webapp

How can I restrict the access of my tomcat home page and How can I make my webapp to show up in the browser when I hit the IP address?

The workers.properties and mod_jk.conf (included in the httpd.conf) is as follows:

workers.properties

```
worker.list=worker1 
# Set properties for worker (ajp13) 
worker.worker1.type=ajp13 
worker.worker1.host=localhost
worker.worker1.port=8009
```

mod_jk.conf

```
JkShmFile /etc/httpd/logs/mod_jk.shm
JkWorkersFile /etc/httpd/conf/workers.properties
JkLogFile /etc/httpd/logs/mod_jk.log
# Select the log format
#JkLogStampFormat [%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y]
# JkOptions indicate to send SSL KEY SIZE,
JkOptions +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat -ForwardDirectories
# JkRequestLogFormat set the request format
#JkRequestLogFormat “%w %V %T”
JkMount /* worker1
```

**EDIT**

I have found a solution for my problem. I renamed my webapp.war to ROOT.war. Now I am able to access the archive directly with the ip:

- IP address (xx.xx.xx.xx) - shows me the home page of my webapp

Is this a clean solution?

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mod_proxy instead of mod_jk

```
vi /etc/httpd/conf.d/proxy.conf

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ ajp://localhost:8009/$1 [P,QSA,L]

service httpd restart
```

To prevent direct access to Tomcat, just block any port other than port 80